# Unable to update background-color of nested div in group of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've hit a road block and I'm not sure where to look.

I have a single div that is 200px by 200px. Within that I have 4 other divs that are 65px by 65px and they are positioned absolute and aligned to all 4 corners of the outer div. I have created a function that when a user clicks on one of the inner divs, that div color is updated and the 3 other divs background-colors are reset. Currently, if I click either of the top 2 divs it works. If I click either of the bottom 2 divs, it doesn't work.

I have a feeling it has something to do with z-index and maybe block alignment, but that is just a guess now.

I've added my code below.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts1.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  BuildHandler();
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="mini_container">
    <div id="top_left" class="mini_boxes"></div>
    <div id="top_right" class="mini_boxes"></div>
    <div id="low_left" class="mini_boxes"></div>
    <div id="low_right" class="mini_boxes"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**scripts1.js**

```
function BoxClicked(event){
  var targetBoxID = event.target.id;
  switch (targetBoxID)
  {
    case "top_left":
      $("#top_left").css("background-color","#0099FF");
      $("#top_right").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
      $("#low_left").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
      $("#low_right").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
      break;
    case "top_right":
      $("#top_left").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
      $("#top_right").css("background-color","#0099FF");
      $("#low_left").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
      $("#low_right").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
    case "low_left":
      $("#top_left").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
      $("#top_right").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
      $("#low_left").css("background-color","#0099FF");
      $("#low_right").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
    case "low_right":
      $("#top_left").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
      $("#top_right").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
      $("#low_left").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
      $("#low_right").css("background-color","#0099FF");
  }
}

function BuildHandler(){
  var theBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("mini_boxes");
  for(i=0;i<theBoxes.length;i++){
    theBoxes[i].addEventListener('click', BoxClicked, false);
  }
}
```

**style1.css**

```
#mini_container{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background-color:#C4CFCE;
position:relative;
z-index:100;
}

.mini_boxes{
  width:65px;
  height:65px;
  background-color:#99CCFF;
  z-index:200;
}

#top_left{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}

#top_right{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
}

#low_left{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
}

#low_right{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  right:0px;
}
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you create a fiddle for your code so that its easy for people to debug

Comment: Can you please provide your code in fiddle??

Comment: Use jquery to attach the click event, Plus the code is way more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

Do you meant this one?

[Please see this JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vk2Wy/)

I haven't changed your CSS or HTML code. I removed all script from HTML page and script file.

This only I added

```
$( ".mini_boxes" ).on( "click", function() {
  $(".mini_boxes").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
   $(this).css("background-color","#0099FF");
});
```

Comment: This is not an answer. Very useful **comment** though.

Comment: oops, sorry. I misread this. I though it was only a copy of the above cod in a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

In your switch case you do not have break; statement for all the cases, adding that will fix your problem and also you have mistyped #low_left and #low_right to #bottom_left, #bottom_right respectively

Comment: Actually, that is an error with my copy and paste. I do have break statements for all my cases and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Abhay. Did you change my code at all? It looks exactly like the code I'm using, but in your jsfiddle it works.

Comment: I changed the two stuff i told nothing more

Answer (score 0):

Your code is overly complicated, simplify it to two lines

```
function boxClicked(event){
    $(".mini_boxes").css("background-color","#99CCFF");  //reset all of the elements to default color
    $(this).css("background-color","#0099FF");  //set the background of the one clicked
}
$("#mini_container").on("click",".mini_boxes", boxClicked);   //attach the event only to the table and use event bubbling to your advantage
```

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/vk2Wy/5/) is your code in working condtion. You have implemented code on wrong ID and break was missing from switch - case.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  BuildHandler();
});

function BoxClicked(event){
  var targetBoxID = event.target.id;

  switch (targetBoxID)
  {
    case "top_left":
      $("#top_left").css("background-color","#0099FF");
      $("#top_right").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
      $("#low_left").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
      $("#low_right").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
      break;
    case "top_right":
      $("#top_left").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
      $("#top_right").css("background-color","#0099FF");
      $("#low_left").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
      $("#low_right").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
          break;
    case "low_left":
      $("#top_left").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
      $("#top_right").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
      $("#low_left").css("background-color","#0099FF");
      $("#low_right").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
          break;
    case "low_right":
      $("#top_left").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
      $("#top_right").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
      $("#low_left").css("background-color","#99CCFF");
      $("#low_right").css("background-color","#0099FF");
          break;
  }
}

function BuildHandler(){
  var theBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("mini_boxes");
  for(i=0;i<theBoxes.length;i++){
    theBoxes[i].addEventListener('click', BoxClicked, false);
  }
}
```

CSS changes:

```
#low_left{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
}

#low_right{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  right:0px;
}
```